# jquery validator - addClassRules

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am trying to add class rules but doesn't seem to work correctly.

On submit of the form, it only validates the first textbox while onblur of the second textbox, the errors are shown.

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    contactvalues: {
        minlength: 10
    },
    email: {
        email: true
    }
});
$("#extracontacts").validate();
```

where #extracontacts is the id of the FORM.

this is (a summary of) the HTML of the form:

```
<form id="extracontacts" action="/toolbox/contact/manage/save" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="contacts_value_1" value="negative@gmail.com" name="contacts_value[]" class="contactvalues email valid">
    <input type="text" id="contacts_value_2" value="testing" name="contacts_value[]" class="contactvalues email">           
</form>
```

also, if I edit the classes of the inputs after document.ready(), do I have to recall `$("#extracontacts").validate();`?

Comment: are you using php or asp.net?

Comment: @AndreaTurri im using PHP, does it make any difference? :s

Comment: yes, asp.net render the ID in different way. my code show how take that ID. If you use php is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you also need an input submit to your form (my submit input ID will be just "sumbit_form"):

```
function InitValidations() {

    function setContactsRules() {

        $('#contacts_value_1').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'please type your email',
                email: 'please type a valid email'
            }
        });

        $('#contacts_value_2').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'please type something'
            }
        });

    $('#submit_form').click(function (event) {

        var isValid = $("#extracontacts").validate();

        setContactsRules();

        if (!isValid) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    InitValidations();

});
```

Hope it helps. Regards.

Comment: Answers on SO are expected to be specific to the question, not some other's code the OP must modify to suit his needs.

Comment: it's a valid example. Just compare the steps.

Comment: I did not say it was an invalid example.  I said it does not _specifically_ answer _his_ question.  Just reformat it so that it answers his question exactly and nobody has to compare any steps.

Comment: Ok done, you was right, now it match the real needs of the question. Hope it works for him because is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your validation like this

```
$(function(){
$("#extracontacts").validate({
 rules: {
    name: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 3,
     maxlength: 50,
 },     


messages: {
    name: {   
       required: "Your name is Required input",
       minlength: "The Postman demands at least {3} characters",
       maxlength: "Please, no more than {50} characters"
     }, 
 });
 });
```

Comment: the problem with using the name is that the name of the inputs to validate have the brackets '[]' which in your case are invalid but anyway, i can't use names since I will be removing/adding/changing the inputs & their validation through javascript... so it's better to use classes

Comment: The names was just an example, it wwasn't configured to your specific text. The point was to validate and add the rules in the same script